# Combine terraform locals variables

Tags: terraform

Can you guide me on how to combine locals? This is not working though some online docs advise to frame this way. Appreciate your help, thanks!

```
# see README.md for developer guide
# prepare subscription where resources are created
locals {
  location_code           = "weu"
  environment_code        = "test"
}

locals {
  kv_name = "oamp-kv-${local.environment_code}-${location_code}"
  ai_name = "oamp-ai-${local.environment_code}-${location_code}"
}

# prepare azure rm configuration
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~>2.15.0"
    use_msi = true
    features {}
}
```

### Validation

```
Error: Invalid reference

  on main.tf line 20, in locals:
  20:   kv_name = "oamp-kv-${local.environment_code}-${location_code}"

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

Comment: Did you try to prefix `location_code` with `local` ? `"oamp-kv-${local.environment_code}-${local.location_code}"`

Comment: *** how could I have missed that! I will prefix and test right away. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reference local variables into locals as it is written in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html).

> As shown above, local values can be referenced from elsewhere in the
> module with an expression like local.common_tags, **and locals can
> reference each other** in order to build more complex values from
> simpler ones.
>
> The error come from the fact you need to prefix with an attribute
> access your resource. However you did not prefix `location_code`.

In you code you miss to prefix access attribute `local` before `location_code`.

What you need to do is prefix correctly your variables :

```
# see README.md for developer guide
# prepare subscription where resources are created
locals {
  location_code           = "weu"
  environment_code        = "test"
}

locals {
  kv_name = "oamp-kv-${local.environment_code}-${local.location_code}"
  ai_name = "oamp-ai-${local.environment_code}-${local.location_code}"
}

# prepare azure rm configuration
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~>2.15.0"
    use_msi = true
    features {}
}
```

Comment: This is just a typo really. I'm not sure it justifies being kept around as a question/answer combo and as such I've voted to close it instead.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: This already works in the same `locals` block.